# Align multiple absolute positioned elements one underneath the other

Tags: css, position, alignment, less

As described in the title: Say I have a given HTML structure and would like to achieve that by using just CSS (I also have LESS in my project but am completely new to it). I could wrap the elements in another.. but I'd prefer to not manipulate the DOM for that if possible.

Simplified Markup:

```
 <div class="mummy">
      <a class="child" href="#">Boo</a>
      <a class="child" href="#">Boo</a>
      <a class="child" href="#">Boo</a>
      <a class="child" href="#">Boo</a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.mummy {
      position: relative;
      width: 9em;
      height: 9em;
      background: green;
    }

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: 2em;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

Of course the elements overlap because they all have the same position. `margin-top` seems to be the right option, but how to calculate it?

As I use LESS I could declare a variable for the height and then say `@varHeight*n`. But I do not know the index (n) of the current element.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hoffs/5cw35616/1/)

Thx for any advice..

Comment: How many such elements would your container have? Is it dynamic? Based on your statement I assume that it might be but just want to be clear.

Comment: @Harry the amount of the children is dynamic, yes. Not more then up to 10, but dynamic ..

Comment: Well if it is only upto 10 then can't your write static selectors for 10 children (or) is it the repetition that you are trying to avoid? You could use loops in Less but the output CSS would still have 10 selectors.

Comment: The easiest way to do this, is to not use `absolute` and just let the boxes flow like they are intended to. If you want to have more control about the positions after the rendition you could use the [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property of `flex`. LESS or SASS wont help you doing anything you can not do with plain css in the end of the day. These tools just help you automatize and organize some of the writing process.

Comment: @Harry, I could do this and if there is no other way I'd have to I suppose. But isn't it "overflow" when I just have 2 elements? And what if someday someone thinks an 11th element would be great? I thought from a QS point of view it should be really dynamic.

Comment: No, it won't overflow (not the correct word in a CSS context) but it would just produce dummy selectors which won't match any element. If somebody adds in a 11th element tomorrow, they'd just have to change the loop's count parameter. It would have been good if there was a different and dynamic way but that's only possible with JS. If you want I can give you a solution for all. (*Note: I assume you didn't mean content overflowing the parent when parent's height is lower than sum of content height. That's an entirely different thing.*)

Comment: @NicoO How would I achieve the same positions of the children as shown in jsfiddle without position: absolute? I think Pre Processors help us a lot - also with calculating, but unfortunately in this case I do not know how.

Comment: @ho.s like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5cw35616/2/ ?

Comment: @Harry My vocabulary did not know another word than overflow. I meant like "trash".. not really needed. Ok then, with jquery I'll also get it working. I thought it should have to be possible with just CSS

Comment: @Harry It is not possible to "do away with position: absolute". Won't need a change to the title, it is correct. I just wondered what NicoO meant and asked.

Comment: Ok, so do you need an answer with the methods that I had mentioned (or) you know your jQuery solution and are going to proceed with that?

Comment: Sorry, no I do not need a jquery solution I can manage that. Thanks for considering..

Comment: And you don't need the Less solution also right?

Comment: Not for the loop with max of 10 elements..

Comment: @NicoO Thanks a lot for your suggestion, would be very elegant and slick, but unfortunately I really need to use position:absolute due to other layout "stuff" in the project here..

Answer (score 2):

If you need to keep the same HTML structure, you can remove `position:absolute` from your `.child` class.

The property `display: block` will display your elements as a block so you will have them one underneath the other.

More information about `display` property can be found here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

There are also other solutions you could consider, although, removing `position: absolute` from your code is the most simple and straight forward in my opinion. Some other ideas could be:

- Flexbox
- display:table
- JavaScript

```css
.mummy {
  position: relative;
  width: 9em;
  height: auto;
  background: green;
}

.child {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mummy">
  <a class="child" href="#">Boo 1</a>
  <a class="child" href="#">Boo 2</a>
  <a class="child" href="#">Boo 3</a>
  <a class="child" href="#">Boo 4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. As I asked in the title I need to have the elements position:absolute. Seems the answer to my question is, that it is not possible or just for a given amount of elements. In my fiddle the anchor tags are already display:block.(And ... where has .mummy gone ?? :-))

Comment: @ho.s it is possible to do it using posiiton:absolute if you are willing to use JavaScript for it (I mention this option in my answer). But as you wrote in your question that you need a CSS solution I did not write the details in my answer. Do you think using JS is it an option to you? If yes I will edit my answer. :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Considering same HTML/CSS structure without removing position:absolute. Assuming only 10 child items on any scenarios. have a look at the preview at

```
div a:nth-child(2n){margin-top:2em;border:2px solid green;}
div a:nth-child(3n){margin-top:4em;border:2px solid yellow;}
div a:nth-child(4n){margin-top:6em;border:2px solid blue;}
div a:nth-child(5n){margin-top:8em;border:2px solid cyan;}
div a:nth-child(6n){margin-top:10em;border:2px solid black;}
div a:nth-child(7n){margin-top:12em;border:2px solid silver;}
div a:nth-child(8n){margin-top:14em;border:2px solid violet;}
div a:nth-child(9n){margin-top:16em;border:2px solid black;}
div a:nth-child(10n){margin-top:18em;border:2px solid white;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/1b3rcjas/.

Hope this helps